# Converting circular structure to JSON axios error

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, axios

I am getting an error in node when calling an api function with axios,
Ther error is:
ERROR with result:TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON     --> starting at object with constructor 'ClientRequest'     |     property 'socket' -> object with constructor 'TLSSocket'     --- property '_httpMessage' closes the circle

the function is:

```
    const createUser= (protocolPhone,identifier,accountname,isExtraField,fieldName,linkField) =>{
return new Promise (function(resolve,reject){
    if(protocolPhone)
    {
        if(isExtraField)
        var data = JSON.stringify({"telephone1":identifier,"Originatingleadcode":"4","accountname":accountname,"pcfsystemfield54":linkField});
        else
        var data = JSON.stringify({"telephone1":identifier,"Originatingleadcode":"4","accountname":accountname});
    }
    else
    {
    if(isExtraField)
    var data = JSON.stringify({"emailaddress1":identifier,"Originatingleadcode":"4","accountname":accountname,"pcfsystemfield54":linkField});
    else
    var data = JSON.stringify({"emailaddress1":identifier,"Originatingleadcode":"4","accountname":accountname});
    }

    var config = {
      method: 'post',
      url: 'https://api.dontwanttopublish.co.il/api/record/1',
      headers: { 
        'Tokenid': globalToken, 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
        'Cookie': 'AWSALB=9M7HrSd7TE6JXFgma6uKO30rMoxJYcmP3coCeXl+YxgYUmNf7Sd7KbMOc+TX5XXn97iop3NFXaJobF81a9SwlrzAXoMzrROcdDcdWkKDC2IQvA//9ba99D8i/M5Z; AWSALBCORS=9M7HrSd7TE6JXFgma6uKO30rMoxJYcmP3coCeXl+YxgYUmNf7Sd7KbMOc+TX5XXn97iop3NFXaJobF81a9SwlrzAXoMzrROcdDcdWkKDC2IQvA//9ba99D8i/M5Z'
      },
      data : data
    };

    axios(config)
    .then(function (response) {
    //  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
      //return JSON.stringify(response.data);

          resolve(response);


    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
      
      reject(error);
    });  

}).catch((err) =>{
    console.log("Error inside createpowerLinkUser"+err)
    logger.log("Error inside createpowerLinkUser"+err)

})
}
```

The error happens here:

```
                        const createPowerLinkClient = PowerLinkAPIFunctions.createPowerLinkClient(true,clientIdentifier, clientName, true, "pcfsystemfield54", "https://app.glassix.com/" + credentials.apiKey + "/tickets" + ticketId).then((result) => {
                        console.log("Function: createPowerLinkClient,success with result:"+result);
                        logger.logError("Function: createPowerLinkClient ,success with result:"+result);
                    }).catch((err) =>{
                        console.log("Function: createPowerLinkClient ,ERROR with result:"+err)
                        logger.logError("Function: createPowerLinkClient ,ERROR with result:"+err)
                        res.sendStatus(400).end();
                    })
```

I now corrected the JSON.Stringify so i don't get an error but it only prints [object], how do i access the info of this object?

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Sidenote, you don't need the complicated `return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => axios.post().then( (response) => resolve(response))`. You can simply `return await axios.post()`.

Comment: Just return `axios.post()` there isn't any point in `await`ing if you immediately return whatever value you get.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, can you maybe refer me to a link explaining more about that? and as for topic, the issue was that i JSON.Stringify the response, now when i am not doing that it only prints [object][object] but how can i view the object?

Comment: Your error message shows that you're trying to `JSON.stringify()` some sort of system object like a `req` or `res` from express, or an `http` object. Those objects have circular references in them, and also have system properties that make no sense stringified. Can you tell which line of your code has the error? If so [edit] your question and we'll try to help you further.

Comment: hey @O.Jones , I have edited the thread, please take a look.